# confusion on chordal distance formula for stereographic projection on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

To calculate the distance I write $d(N,z_1)=\sqrt{(x−0)^2+(y−0)^2+(1−z)^2}$. Then I get $d(N,z_1)=\sqrt{(1+(z_1)^2)−2z+z^2}$ but the actual formula does have the $2z+z^2$ term, can anyone please help I am trying to find distance between a point on Riemann sphere and north pole of Riemann sphere. At north pole the coordinate are $(0,0,1)$ so I put it in the equation but didn't got the formula,what am I missing?

Comment: The two distance formulas are algebraically equivalent. The "actual formula" must have a sign error in it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers,i found the solution